# Want Travis to fail on warnings in tests

Tags: r, travis-ci, testthat

I'm using `testthat` in R, and I'd like travis to fail my build if warnings are generated within tests. I have `warnings_are_errors: true`, but it seems warnings generated within tests don't propagate to that level. Is there a way to set this up? Here's a [build](https://travis-ci.org/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/builds/353037067) that passes with a warning from this test:

`test_that("warnings cause travis to fail", {
  odd <- 1:2 * 1:5
  expect_equal(length(odd), 5)
})`

Comment: can you include a link to that exact branch & file containing the test?  It's not coming up in the search [because it's not in the master/default branch](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/).

Comment: @wibeasley https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/blob/levy936travis/tests/testthat/test-warnings_fail.R

Comment: I'm wondering if the function/test is even called (although [`tests/test-all.R`](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/blob/aa3789baecc677a757b2fdf00ab99be20fcd6e4b/tests/testthat.R) looks fine).  Can you intentionally throw an error from that function, and see if the check fails in Travis?

Comment: I think something is disconnected.  The [travis yaml](https://github.com/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/blob/a9f9e28d1e347515f5d76f24ffb8912bb9237789/.travis.yml) file specifies a matrix of jobs, but I don't see multiple jobs [associated with that commit](https://travis-ci.org/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/builds/353037067).

Comment: @wibeasley -- there was a problem with the matrix, thanks. That's fixed now but the build still passes. The tests do run; here was a build that failed with an error in the same test: https://travis-ci.org/HealthCatalyst/healthcareai-r/builds/353046003

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://community.rstudio.com/t/fail-ci-on-warnings-in-tests/6187) with testthat authors, it sounds like there isn't currently an easy way to do this, but they'll consider adding an option for it in the future. Here's the [GH issue](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/731) for future reference.